# page content when tab changed in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

background.js

```
var htmlcontent = null;

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
onWindowLoad();
alert(htmlcontent);
});

chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(function(){
onWindowLoad();
alert(htmlcontent);
});

function onWindowLoad() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
file: "getPagesSource.js"
}, function() {
if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
htmlcontent = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.extension.lastError.message;
}
});
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
if (request.action == "getSource") {
htmlcontent = request.source;
}
});
```

getPagesSource.js

```
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
return document.body.innerText ;
}

chrome.extension.sendMessage({
action: "getSource",
source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

I am developing a chrome extension. I am able to get the Body Content of the current window on a reload but I am not able to get the content when I change a tab. The previous tab's content is getting saved. Am I using the wrong API? Or How do I trigger the onUpdate functionality when I change a tab in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it.

I am printing the html content in the chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(function(). At that instant, I still wouldn't have got the value.

The htmlcontent value will be set only at the chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function().

So if you try and print the htmlcontent, you still would be having the previous tab's content.

So the flow is,

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
onWindowLoad();
});

function onWindowLoad() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
file: "getPagesSource.js"
}, function() {
if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
htmlcontent = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' +     chrome.extension.lastError.message;
}
});
}

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
if (request.action == "getSource") {
htmlcontent = request.source;
//call whatever function from here on so that htmlcontent will have the selected tab's content.
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By "when I change a tab" do you mean changing which tab is active?

Make sure you understand the parameters for the events and callbacks in the tabs API:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

I'm not certain what you're trying to do, but the tabs.onActivated event is fired when you change which tab is active. Maybe you want to add a listener for that rather than tabs.onHighlighted.

Also, chrome.tabs.executeScript's first argument should be the tab ID for the tab you want to execute the script in (if null, it executes in the active tab). The callbacks for the tabs events have additional parameters, e.g. which window the tab is in, or whether the tab is still loading or completed.

Comment: "Change the tab" I mean, switching in between previously loaded tabs. What chrome API do I need to use so that, chomre.tabs.executeScript can execute on the "CHANGED TAB"? To give a clearer view, say I have tabs 1,2 and 3 loaded in my chrome browser. Currently I am in tab 1. When I switch to tab 2, I need to capture the innertext. But in my code, when I switch to tab 2, I am getting the innerText of the Tab 1. How can I get the innerText of the changed Tab and not the text of the previous tab?

Comment: @nikhil https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated says "onActivated -- Fires when the active tab in a window changes." use it like `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function callback)` in your background.js since chrome.* isn't available in other parts of your extension, except for sending messages to/from background.js